# regexp в postgresql в select разделе для поиска и преобразования строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Добрый день.

Задача следующая: имеется строка вида 'Channel aps-61.ds0Grp-1.1.5.3.1:0.0'. Необходимо в postgres преобразовать ее (вероятно, с помощью regexp) в вид: aps-61-VC4-1-TU-1.5.3. Т.е. из 1.1.5.3.1:0.0 берется первое число и записывается после VC4- , а следующие три числа 1.5.3 записываются в виде TU-1.5.3. Последующие цифры откидываются.

Пробовал данную задачу решать примерно так:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('Channel aps-61.ds0Grp-1.1.5.3.1:0.0', 'aps-[0-9]{2}')
```

Но дальше мысль не продвинулась, регулярные выражения даются с трудом. Можно, конечно, наверное подключить в postgres модуль python и создать функцию, но возможно можно меньшей кровью обойтись. Если есть идеи, буду благодарен.

Comment: Вам regexp_replace() нужна

Comment: Да, его тоже пробовал, только толком не разобрался. Разобрался, как найти первое вхождение (aps-61), а как остальное и где подставить в шаблон - не выходит каменный цветок.

Comment: `regexp_replace(x,'.*?(aps-\d+).*?-(\d+)\.(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*$','\1-VC4-\2-TU-\3')` https://regex101.com/r/tAClFJ/1

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, работает! И за ссылку отдельная благодарность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю какой синтаксис у postgresql, но регулярка была бы такой:

```
preg_replace("/.*(aps-\d{2})[^-]*-(\d)\.(\d\.\d\.\d).*/", "$1-VC4-$2-TU-$3", $input_lines);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hVa